# Python doesn't work: ImportError: No module named 'logging'

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, module, gunicorn

I'm experiencing a very strange issue on my Digitalocean Ubuntu droplet, where Python 2.7 gives me the following error:

```
  from instagram import InstagramAuthentication, InstagramAPI
  File "/root/instagram_insights/socialgraphs-final-assignment/instagram.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 2, in <module>
    import logging
ImportError: No module named logging
```

In fact, I can't do **anything** with Python:

1. If I'm trying to reinstall python through `apt-get` I get the same error
2. If I'm trying to execute a any pip command, e.g. `pip search logging`, I get the error
3. I can't even create a new virtualenv by doing `virtualenv venv` without getting the same error

My `PYTHONPATH` looks like this:

`['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn-19.3.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']`

The funny thing is that the error appeared out of the blue until I restarted gunicorn, which is the WSGI server I'm using to host my Flask site.

Before it happened I was fiddling with logs in `nginx`, but I can't see how that should have affected my Python installation.

Comment: You could try adding `site-packages` to your `PYTHONPATH`:  `sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')`

Comment: Appending doesn't work. It's not only a issue when executing my own apps, but also when using `pip`

Comment: `logging` is in stdlib (`/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/`). Does `/usr/bin/python -S -c'import logging'` work?

Comment: Try running python from the absolute path: `/usr/local/bin/python2.7 XX.py` or in the shebang line: `#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7`  (Or `/usr/bin/python2.7` depending on your install)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use system-wide python and not virtualenv-from-somewhere:

```
which python
```

Try to find out where this module is located:

```
sudo updatedb
locate logging | grep python
```

Then try adding this path to PYTHONPATH

Comment: is there an option if updatedb is not available (and locate neither)?

Comment: doing that, ends up in further errors such as `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logging.handlers'; 'logging' is not a package`

Comment: rename your file `logging.py` that you have either in the same folder or somewhere in `sys.path`. There is a module that overrides system's one.