# ImportError: No module named 'logging.handlers'; 'logging' is not a package

Tags: python-3.x

I will use RotatingFileHandler in Python 3.5.3 64 bit

I try a lot of example, but by all I got the same Error after few lines:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
```

but I got the folling Error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'logging.handlers'; 'logging' is not a package
```

Comment: This sounds like an installation problem, have a read through the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945725/python-doesnt-work-importerror-no-module-named-logging) to see if anything helps.

What system are you running and what does your `PYTHONPATH` have on it?

Answer (score 27):

Sorry, I was not able to read the Errormessage in the right way. My mistake was the filename logging.py - the Py-file was opened by himself

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python-Projects\logging.py", line 1, in <module>
    import logging
  File "C:\Python-Projects\logging.py", line 2, in <module>
    from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
ImportError: No module named 'logging.handlers'; 'logging' is not a package
```

Solution is rename the file to anything else like logging-test.py and be sure, that there is no other file like logging.py.

I spent 3 days for that mistake. Thanks for support.