# Pip Import Error No module named logging

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pip

Whenever I am running any command using pip, I am getting the following error. I have tried uninstalling python,pip and reinstalling them back again. I also used

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then updated and upgraded

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And once again installed python and pip. I am still getting the same error whenever I run any command using pip.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
from pip import main
File "/home/shashank/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
File "/home/shashank/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
from pip.download import path_to_url
File "/home/shashank/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 34, in <module>
from pip.utils.logging import indent_log 
ImportError: No module named logging
```

Can anybody suggest a solution?
**Edit**
I have read the question which is used to flag my question as a duplicate.
I am not using a virtual environment and I have already tried the answer given over there. Moreover I am encountering a problem when I run pip in my terminal
The output of the command

```
locate logging 

/etc/java-9-openjdk/logging.properties
/home/shashank/.local/share/Trash/files/logging.py
/home/shashank/.local/share/Trash/files/logging.pyc
/home/shashank/.local/share/Trash/info/logging.py.trashinfo
/home/shashank/.local/share/Trash/info/logging.pyc.trashinfo
/lib/lsb/init-functions.d/50-ubuntu-logging
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/jmods/java.logging.jmod
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/lib/logging.properties
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging
/usr/lib/python2.7/logging
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/logging.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/logging.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.pyc
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UnityTweakTool/config/logging.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist packages/UnityTweakTool/config/__pycache__/logging.cpython-35.pyc
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/plainbox/impl/logging.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/plainbox/impl/__pycache__/logging.cpython-35.pyc
/usr/lib/python3.5/logging
/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__pycache__
/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py
/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/handlers.py
/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-35.pyc
/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__pycache__/config.cpython-35.pyc
/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__pycache__/handlers.cpython-35.pyc
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/categories/applications-microblogging-panel.png
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/categories/22/applications-microblogging-panel.svg
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/categories/24/applications-microblogging-panel.svg
 /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/categories/22/applications-microblogging-panel.svg
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/categories/24/applications-microblogging-panel.svg
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic/include/config/fusion/logging.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic/include/config/scsi/logging.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic/include/config/sfc/mcdi/logging.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic/include/config/fusion/logging.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic/include/config/scsi/logging.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic/include/config/sfc/mcdi/logging.h
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python doesn't work: ImportError: No module named 'logging'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945725/python-doesnt-work-importerror-no-module-named-logging)

Comment: Which version of python and pip are you using. Can you confirm pip is installed?

Comment: yes, python-2.7.12

Comment: Check that /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages inside your PYTHONPATH. Then add "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/".

Comment: "echo $PATH" to check values. "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils"  to modify.

Comment: I did it, and I am getting another import error telling me that there is no module named handlers  @DmitryShilyaev Terminal looks like this  ` File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
 File "/home/shashank/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
 import logging
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/logging.py", line 5, in <module>
import logging.handlers
ImportError: No module named handlers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious from your traceback that you have a version of `pip` installed in your home directory, at `/home/shashank/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/`. Delete that. If you aren't certain what else is contained there, better delete all `/home/shashank/.local/lib/python2.7`. After you delete it, it will use the system's default `pip` that you installed with `apt`.